# Missing provider for goog.date when recompiling the build.py file - google blockly

Tags: javascript, blockly, google-blockly

We have added field_date in blockly.js file and trying to recompile the build.py file but when running, it is throwing an error of missing provider goog.date . How can we solve this issue we are using latest blockly version.

Comment: check if google closure library is in the same directory level as google-blockly. maybe [this](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/modify/web/closure) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is slowly removing the closure library dependencies from blockly. So closure library is not added by default anymore.

The field_date depends on closure library. So it needs to be added manually into the library and the library has to be rebuilt. The process to achieve this is mentioned as a warning text in the blockly [FieldDate documentation](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/create-custom-blocks/fields/built-in-fields/date) -

> **Warning**: Due to its limited use and large footprint, `FieldDate` is not
>   compiled into Blockly by default. To use it you will need to **require**
>   it and rebuild. Add `goog.require('Blockly.FieldDate')` to your project,
>   or uncomment it inside blockly.js to enable it. `FieldDate` also depends
>   on the Closure Library which is no longer compiled into Blockly by
>   default. You will need to add `google-closure-library` to your
>   package.json and rebuild with the `--closure-library` flag: `gulp build
>   --closure-library`.